# Calculator Android App

Tags: java, android, calculator

I was looking for a review on my coding. Since I'm planning to get a job as a Android Programmer in the long run.

This is my first calculator app, which I did by self learning Programming. I have no other Programming Langauge experience.

So I would love to hear how bad my coding is?
Which areas I need improving on?
What I should have used instead of repeating my self, which is bad coding as I understand.

```
private Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btnZero, btnDoubleZero, btnEqual, btnMultiply, btnDevide,
        btnPlus, btnMinus, btnClean, btnPoint;
private TextView textView1, totalSum;
private String lastInputNumber = "";
private double num1 = 0;
private double num2 = 0;
private double tempCount = 0;
private double tempSum = 0;

private int myClickCount = 0;

private boolean nSwitch = true;
private boolean equalSwitch = false;

String stringMinus = " - ";

String[] operation = {
    };
String[] lastNumber = {
    };

ArrayList<String> op = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> ln = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    btn9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    btnZero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btnDoubleZero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    btnEqual = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button20);
    btnMultiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);
    btnDevide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
    btnPlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button16);
    btnMinus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button15);
    btnClean = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button19);
    btnPoint = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn7.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn8.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn9.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnZero.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDoubleZero.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnEqual.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMultiply.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDevide.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnClean.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPoint.setOnClickListener(this);

    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    totalSum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    textView1.setTypeface(tf);
    totalSum.setTypeface(tf);

    Typeface btnTf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");

    btnMultiply.setTypeface(btnTf);
    btnDevide.setTypeface(btnTf);

    btnEqual.setTypeface(btnTf);

    btnClean.setTypeface(btnTf);
    btnMinus.setTypeface(btnTf);
    btnPlus.setTypeface(btnTf);
    btnZero.setTypeface(btnTf);
    btnDoubleZero.setTypeface(btnTf);
    btn1.setTypeface(btnTf);
    btn2.setTypeface(btnTf);
    btn3.setTypeface(btnTf);
    btn4.setTypeface(btnTf);
    btn5.setTypeface(btnTf);
    btn6.setTypeface(btnTf);
    btn7.setTypeface(btnTf);
    btn8.setTypeface(btnTf);
    btn9.setTypeface(btnTf);

    // makes the textviews scrollable
    textView1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    totalSum.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button3:
        // log that you clicked one
        Log.d("OSSI", "button 1 was clicked");
        // First if switch is to check of equal was used
        if (equalSwitch == true) {

        } else {
            // add one to the existing textView1 string
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + "1");

            // my click counter plus one
            myClickCount++;
            // Bollean switch so operators cant be called twice
            nSwitch = false;
        }

      break;
    case R.id.button7:
        // log that you clicked two
        Log.d("OSSI", "button 2 was clicked");
        // First if switch is to check of equal was used
        if (equalSwitch == true) {

        } else {
            // add two to the existing textView1 string
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + "2");

            // my click counter plus one
            myClickCount++;
            // Bollean switch so operators cant be called twice
            nSwitch = false;
        }

      break;
    case R.id.button11:
        // log that you clicked three
        Log.d("OSSI", "button 3 was clicked");
        // First if switch is to check of equal was used
        if (equalSwitch == true) {

        } else {
            // add three to the existing textView1 string
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + "3");

            // my click counter plus one
            myClickCount++;
            // Bollean switch so operators cant be called twice
            nSwitch = false;
        }

      break;
    case R.id.button2:
        // log that you clicked four
        Log.d("OSSI", "button 4 was clicked");
        // First if switch is to check of equal was used
        if (equalSwitch == true) {

        } else {
            // add four to the existing textView1 string
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + "4");

            // my click counter plus one
            myClickCount++;
            // Bollean switch so operators cant be called twice
            nSwitch = false;
        }

      break;
    case R.id.button6:
        // log that you clicked five
        Log.d("OSSI", "button 5 was clicked");
        // First if switch is to check of equal was used
        if (equalSwitch == true) {

        } else {
            // add five to the existing textView1 string
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + "5");

            // my click counter plus one
            myClickCount++;
            // Bollean switch so operators cant be called twice
            nSwitch = false;
        }

      break;
    case R.id.button10:
        // log that you clicked six
        Log.d("OSSI", "button 6 was clicked");
        // First if switch is to check of equal was used
        if (equalSwitch == true) {

        } else {
            // add six to the existing textView1 string
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + "6");

            // my click counter plus one
            myClickCount++;
            // Bollean switch so operators cant be called twice
            nSwitch = false;
        }

      break;
    case R.id.button1:
        // log that you clicked seven
        Log.d("OSSI", "button 7 was clicked");
        // First if switch is to check of equal was used
        if (equalSwitch == true) {

        } else {
            // add seven to the existing textView1 string
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + "7");

            // my click counter plus one
            myClickCount++;
            // Bollean switch so operators cant be called twice
            nSwitch = false;
        }

      break;
    case R.id.button5:
        // log that you clicked eight
        Log.d("OSSI", "button 8 was clicked");
        // First if switch is to check of equal was used
        if (equalSwitch == true) {

        } else {
            // add eight to the existing textView1 string
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + "8");

            // my click counter plus one
            myClickCount++;
            // Bollean switch so operators cant be called twice
            nSwitch = false;
        }

      break;
    case R.id.button9:
        // log that you clicked nine
        Log.d("OSSI", "button 9 was clicked");
        // First if switch is to check of equal was used
        if (equalSwitch == true) {

        } else {
            // add nine to the existing textView1 string
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + "9");

            // my click counter plus one
            myClickCount++;
            // Bollean switch so operators cant be called twice
            nSwitch = false;
        }

      break;
    case R.id.button4:
        // log that you clicked zero
        Log.d("OSSI", "button 0 was clicked");

        // First if switch is to check of equal was used
        if (equalSwitch == true) {

        } else {
            // add zero to the existing textView1 string
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + "0");

            // my click counter plus one
            myClickCount++;
            // Bollean switch so operators cant be called twice
            nSwitch = false;
        }

      break;
    case R.id.button8:
        // log that you clicked doublezero
        Log.d("OSSI", "button 00 was clicked");
        if (myClickCount == 0) {

        }
        else if (equalSwitch == true) {

        }
        else {
            // add doublezero to the existing textView1
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + "00");

            // my click counter plus one
            myClickCount += 2;
            // Bollean switch so operators cant be called twice
            nSwitch = false;
        }


      break;
    case R.id.button13:
        Log.d("OSSI", "button / was clicked");
        // checks if ln arraylist has something stored before executing the math code
        if (textView1.length() < 1) {

        }   
        else if (ln.isEmpty()) {
            // Log ln array is Empty
            Log.d("OSSI", "ln is empty");
            // Getting textView1 and parse into an int
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(textView1.getText().toString());
            // Saving the int num1 in sum1 as a String
            String sum1 = Double.toString(num1);
            // Setting text from sum1 to totalSum
            totalSum.setText(sum1);
            // Adding sum1 inside ln string arraylist
            ln.add(sum1);
            // Adding devide symbol to the exsiting textView1 text
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + " / ");
            // Adding devide to the op array list
            op.add("/");
        }
        else if (nSwitch == true) {
            // Save textView1 into lastOperator String
            String lastOperator = textView1.getText().toString();
            // Save String without the last Operator
            String deleteLastOperator = lastOperator.substring(lastOperator.length() - (lastOperator.length()),
                                                                                    lastOperator.length() - 3);
            // Saving the new String without the last Operator
            textView1.setText(deleteLastOperator);
            // Adding new operator to textView1 String
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + " / ");
            // Adding to the op array list
            op.add("/");
            // Removes the first operator from op arraylist
            op.remove(0);
        }
        else {

            // Saving textView1 as lastNumb
            String lastNumb = textView1.getText().toString();

            // A substring of lastNumb String will be saved as lastIput
            // (lastnumb minus the click counter, till the last lastnumb)
            String lastInput = lastNumb.substring(lastNumb.length() - myClickCount, lastNumb.length());

            // Parsing lastInput to into num2 integer
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(lastInput);
            // Parsing String of totalSum into tempSum integer
            tempSum = Double.parseDouble(totalSum.getText().toString());

                if (op.get(0) == "+") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if plus operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum + sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum + num2;
                } 
                else if  (op.get(0) == "-")  {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if minus operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum - sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum - num2;
                }
                else if (op.get(0) == "/") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if devide operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum / sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum / num2;
                }
                else if (op.get(0) == "*") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if multiply operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum * sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum * num2;
                }

                // Math to round 2 decimal number before tempSum will be set into totalSum  
                double mathRound = tempSum;
                double tempSum = Math.round(mathRound*100.0)/100.0;



            // Changing tempSum to a String
            String sumDevide = Double.toString(tempSum);
            // String sumDevide will be the new totalSum text
            totalSum.setText(sumDevide);



            // Adding devide symbol to the exsiting textView1 text
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + " / ");
            // Adding to the op array list
            op.add("/");
            // Removes the first operator from op arraylist
            op.remove(0);
        }
        // my click counter reset to zero
        myClickCount = 0;
        // Equal Switch to false so numbers can be used again
        equalSwitch = false;

        nSwitch = true;
      break;
    case R.id.button14:
        Log.d("OSSI", "button * was clicked");

        if (textView1.length() < 1) {

        }
        // checks if ln arraylist has something stored before executing the math code
        else if (ln.isEmpty()) {
            // Log ln array is Empty
            Log.d("OSSI", "ln is empty");
            // Getting textView1 and parse into an int
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(textView1.getText().toString());
            // Saving the int num1 in sum1 as a String
            String sum1 = Double.toString(num1);
            // Setting text from sum1 to totalSum
            totalSum.setText(sum1);
            // Adding sum1 inside ln string arraylist
            ln.add(sum1);
            // Adding multiply symbol to the exsiting textView1 text
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + " * ");
            // Adding multiply to the op array list
            op.add("*");
        }
        else if (nSwitch == true) {
            // Save textView1 into lastOperator String
            String lastOperator = textView1.getText().toString();
            // Save String without the last Operator
            String deleteLastOperator = lastOperator.substring(lastOperator.length() - (lastOperator.length()),
                                                                                    lastOperator.length() - 3);
            // Saving the new String without the last Operator
            textView1.setText(deleteLastOperator);
            // Adding new operator to textView1 String
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + " * ");
            // Adding to the op array list
            op.add("*");
            // Removes the first operator from op arraylist
            op.remove(0);
        }
        else {

            // Saving textView1 as lastNumb
            String lastNumb = textView1.getText().toString();

            // A substring of lastNumb String will be saved as lastIput
            // (lastnumb minus the click counter, till the last lastnumb)
            String lastInput = lastNumb.substring(lastNumb.length() - myClickCount, lastNumb.length());

            // Parsing lastInput to into num2 integer
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(lastInput);
            // Parsing String of totalSum into tempSum integer
            tempSum = Double.parseDouble(totalSum.getText().toString());

                if (op.get(0) == "+") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if plus operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum + sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum + num2;
                } 
                else if  (op.get(0) == "-")  {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if minus operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum - sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum - num2;
                }
                else if (op.get(0) == "/") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if devide operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum / sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum / num2;
                }
                else if (op.get(0) == "*") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if multiply operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum * sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum * num2;
                }

                // Math to round 2 decimal number before tempSum will be set into totalSum  
                double mathRound = tempSum;
                double tempSum = Math.round(mathRound*100.0)/100.0;

            // Changing tempSum to a String
            String sumMulitply = Double.toString(tempSum);
            // String sumMultiply will be the new totalSum text
            totalSum.setText(sumMulitply);



            // Adding multiply symbol to the exsiting textView1 text
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + " * ");
            // Adding to the op array list
            op.add("*");
            // Removes the first operator from op arraylist
            op.remove(0);
        }
        // my click counter reset to zero
        myClickCount = 0;

        nSwitch = true;
        // Equal Switch to false so numbers can be used again
        equalSwitch = false;
      break;
    case R.id.button15:
        Log.d("OSSI", "button - was clicked");

        if (textView1.length() < 1) {

        }
        // checks if ln arraylist has something stored before executing the math code
        else if (ln.isEmpty()) {
            // Log ln array is Empty
            Log.d("OSSI", "ln is empty");
            // Getting textView1 and parse into an int
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(textView1.getText().toString());
            // Saving the int num1 in sum1 as a String
            String sum1 = Double.toString(num1);
            // Setting text from sum1 to totalSum
            totalSum.setText(sum1);
            // Adding sum1 inside ln string arraylist
            ln.add(sum1);
            // Adding minus symbol to the exsiting textView1 text
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + stringMinus);
            // Adding minus to the op array list
            op.add("-");
        }
        else if (nSwitch == true) {
            // Save textView1 into lastOperator String
            String lastOperator = textView1.getText().toString();
            // Save String without the last Operator
            String deleteLastOperator = lastOperator.substring(lastOperator.length() - (lastOperator.length()),
                                                                                    lastOperator.length() - 3);
            // Saving the new String without the last Operator
            textView1.setText(deleteLastOperator);
            // Adding new operator to textView1 String
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + stringMinus);
            // Adding to the op array list
            op.add("-");
            // Removes the first operator from op arraylist
            op.remove(0);
        }
        else {

                // Saving textView1 as lastNumb
                String lastNumb = textView1.getText().toString();

                // A substring of lastNumb String will be saved as lastIput
                // (lastnumb minus the click counter, till the last lastnumb)
                String lastInput = lastNumb.substring(lastNumb.length() - myClickCount, lastNumb.length());

                // Parsing lastInput to into num2 integer
                num2 = Double.parseDouble(lastInput);
                // Parsing String of totalSum into tempSum integer
                tempSum = Double.parseDouble(totalSum.getText().toString());

                if (op.get(0) == "+") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if plus operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum + sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum + num2;
                } 
                else if  (op.get(0) == "-")  {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if minus operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum - sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum - num2;
                }
                else if (op.get(0) == "/") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if devide operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum / sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum / num2;
                }
                else if (op.get(0) == "*") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if multiply operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum * sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum * num2;
                }

                // Math to round 2 decimal number before tempSum will be set into totalSum  
                double mathRound = tempSum;
                double tempSum = Math.round(mathRound*100.0)/100.0;


            // Changing tempSum to a String
            String sumMinus = Double.toString(tempSum);
            // String sumMinus will be the new totalSum text
            totalSum.setText(sumMinus);



            // Adding multiply symbol to the exsiting textView1 text
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + stringMinus);
            // Adding to the op array list
            op.add("-");
            // Removes the first operator from op arraylist
            op.remove(0);
        }
        // my click counter reset to zero
        myClickCount = 0;

        nSwitch = true;
        // Equal Switch to false so numbers can be used again
        equalSwitch = false;
      break;
    case R.id.button16:
        Log.d("OSSI", "button + was clicked");

        if (textView1.length() < 1) {

        }
        // checks if ln arraylist has something stored before executing the math code
        else if (ln.isEmpty()) {
            // Log ln array is Empty
            Log.d("OSSI", "ln is empty");
            // Getting textView1 and parse into an int
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(textView1.getText().toString());
            // Saving the int num1 in sum1 as a String
            String sum1 = Double.toString(num1);
            // Setting text from sum1 to totalSum
            totalSum.setText(sum1);
            // Adding sum1 inside ln string arraylist
            ln.add(sum1);
            // Adding plus symbol to the exsiting textView1 text
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + " + ");
            // Adding plus to the op array list
            op.add("+");
        }
        else if (nSwitch == true) {
            // Save textView1 into lastOperator String
            String lastOperator = textView1.getText().toString();
            // Save String without the last Operator
            String deleteLastOperator = lastOperator.substring(lastOperator.length() - (lastOperator.length()),
                                                                                    lastOperator.length() - 3);
            // Saving the new String without the last Operator
            textView1.setText(deleteLastOperator);
            // Adding new operator to textView1 String
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + " + ");
            // Adding to the op array list
            op.add("+");
            // Removes the first operator from op arraylist
            op.remove(0);
        }
        else {

            // Saving textView1 as lastNumb
            String lastNumb = textView1.getText().toString();

            // A substring of lastNumb String will be saved as lastIput
            // (lastnumb minus the click counter, till the last lastnumb)
            String lastInput = lastNumb.substring(lastNumb.length() - myClickCount, lastNumb.length());

            // Parsing lastInput to into num2 integer
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(lastInput);
            // Parsing String of totalSum into tempSum integer
            tempSum = Double.parseDouble(totalSum.getText().toString());

                if (op.get(0) == "+") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if plus operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum + sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum + num2;
                    new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(tempSum);
                } 
                else if  (op.get(0) == "-")  {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if minus operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum - sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum - num2;
                }
                else if (op.get(0) == "/") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if devide operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum / sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum / num2;
                }
                else if (op.get(0) == "*") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if multiply operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum * sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum * num2;
                }

                // Math to round 2 decimal number before tempSum will be set into totalSum  
                double mathRound = tempSum;
                double tempSum = Math.round(mathRound*100.0)/100.0;

            // Changing tempSum to a String
            String sumAdition = Double.toString(tempSum);
            // String sumAdition will be the new totalSum text
            totalSum.setText(sumAdition);


            // Adding multiply symbol to the exsiting textView1 text
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + " + ");
            // Adding to the op array list
            op.add("+");
            // Removes the first operator from op arraylist
            op.remove(0);
        }
        // my click counter reset to zero
        myClickCount = 0;

        // Equal Switch to false so numbers can be used again
        equalSwitch = false;

        nSwitch = true;
      break;

    case R.id.button20:
        Log.d("OSSI", "button = was clicked");

        if (myClickCount == 0) {

        }

        else if (ln.isEmpty()) {

        }

        else if (nSwitch == true) {

        }

        else {
            // Saving textView1 as lastNumb
            String lastNumb = textView1.getText().toString();

            // A substring of lastNumb String will be saved as lastIput
            // (lastnumb minus the click counter, till the last lastnumb)
            String lastInput = lastNumb.substring(lastNumb.length() - myClickCount, lastNumb.length());

            // Parsing lastInput to into num2 integer
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(lastInput);
            // Parsing String of totalSum into tempSum integer
            tempSum = Double.parseDouble(totalSum.getText().toString());

                if (op.get(0) == "+") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if plus operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum + sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum + num2;
                } 
                else if  (op.get(0) == "-")  {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if minus operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum - sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum - num2;
                }
                else if (op.get(0) == "/") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if devide operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum / sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum / num2;
                }
                else if (op.get(0) == "*") {
                    Log.d("OSSI", "if multiply operator worked");
                    // Calculating tempSum * sum2
                    tempSum = tempSum * num2;
                }

            // Math to round 2 decimal number before tempSum will be set into totalSum  
            double mathRound = tempSum;
            double tempSum = Math.round(mathRound*100.0)/100.0;


            // Changing tempSum to a String
            String sumEqual = Double.toString(tempSum);
            // String sumMultiply will be the new totalSum text
            totalSum.setText(sumEqual);

            // Adding to the op array list
            op.add("tF");

            // Removes the first operator from op arraylist
            op.remove(0);

            // checks if equal was pressed so no number can be pressed
            equalSwitch = true;
        }

      break;

    case R.id.button12:
        Log.d("OSSI", "button Point was clicked");
        // sets the textView1 to a string
        String string = textView1.getText().toString();
        String pointChecker = string.substring(string.length() - myClickCount, string.length());

        if (equalSwitch == true) {

        }
        else if (string.length() == 0){
            // If string length is 0 no point will added
        }
        else if (myClickCount == 0) {

        }
        else if (pointChecker.contains(".")) {
            // If string contains a point, no new point will added
        }
        else {
            // Adds one point in the TextView after any given number
            textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + ".");
            myClickCount++;
        }
      break;

    case R.id.button19:
        Log.d("OSSI", "button C was clicked");
        textView1.setText("");
        totalSum.setText("");

        this.num1 = 0;
        this.num2 = 0;
        this.tempCount = 0;
        this.tempSum = 0;

        this.myClickCount = 0;

        this.nSwitch = true;
        this.equalSwitch = false;

        op.removeAll(op);
        ln.removeAll(ln);

      break;



    default:
      break;
    }


}
```

Comment: Once you've fixed the things @rolfl suggested below, please post a [follow-up question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/how-to-post-a-follow-up-question) as I think there will be more stuff that can be fixed then!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a large amount of code duplication. The highly technical description of your problem is 'DRY' or Don't Repeat Yourself.

I would say that fixing three issues in your code would make the rest of the code a lot simpler to manage. Once those three are done, you should bring your code back for review.

### 1. Resources

You have completely munged the names of the resources in your Layout.xml file. Your button resources should have ID's that match the button. Why is `R.id.button3` actually `Button btn1`? You should re-identify all your resources and make the resource names match the use of the resource. This is a simple fix, but would have been better to get right the first time around.

### 2. Button Arrays

You should specify your buttons as an array of `Button` and you should populate it accordingly. Even better would be an enum of Button.

```
public enum CalculatorButton {
    ZERO(R.id.CalcZero),
    ONE(R.id.CalcOne),
    ....
    POINT(R.id.CalcPoint),
    ...
    ;


    public static final CalculatorButton getOwner(int buttonid) {
        for (CalculatorButton cb : values()) {
            if (cb.getButtonID() == button) {
                return cb;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private final int calcbutton;
    private CalculatorButton(int calcbutton) {
        this.calcbutton = caclbutton;
    }

    public int getButtonID() {
        return calcbutton;
    }

}
```

Then, when you set up your Activity, you can loop over the enum members:

```
for (CalculatorButton cb : CalculatorButton.values()) {
    cb.getButton().setOnClickListener(this);
    cb.getButton().setTypeface(btnTf)
}
```

Similarly, there are a lot of other places where you can reduce the code footprint using the loop.

### Switch on Enum

With your buttons represented as enum members, your big switch statement can become:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (CalculatorButton.getOwner(v.getId())) {
    case ONE:
          ....
    case POINT:
          ....

}
```

You should have better handling for what you do with the buttons as well, but these three changes will go a long way to making your code more readable.